# MYSQL High CPU Usage and slow queries

Tags: mysql, database, import, mariadb

I have a problem with slow queries during high mysql load. This happens when I import products to woocoomerce using WP All Import. CPU and Memory load during import:

TOP command:

[image: TOP command]

Sample Query before import:

```
SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS hm_posts.ID
    FROM  hm_posts
    WHERE  1=1
      AND  ( ( hm_posts.ID NOT IN (
                        SELECT  object_id
                            FROM  hm_term_relationships
                            WHERE  term_taxonomy_id IN (7) ) ) 
           )
      AND  hm_posts.post_type = 'product'
      AND  (hm_posts.post_status = 'publish'
              OR  hm_posts.post_status = 'private'
           )
    GROUP BY  hm_posts.ID
    ORDER BY  hm_posts.post_date DESC
    LIMIT  0, 10
```

The query took 0.0095 seconds.

The same query when importing:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS hm_posts.ID FROM hm_posts WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( hm_posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT object_id FROM hm_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (7) ) ) ) AND hm_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (hm_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR hm_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY hm_posts.ID ORDER BY hm_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

The query took 0.0174 seconds.

So time has been increased by almost 100%. My whole site loads about 40% slower and CPU usage is only about 45%. I guess it shouldn't be like that?

my.cnf settings:

```css
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user  = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port  = 3306
basedir  = /usr
datadir  = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir  = /tmp
lc_messages_dir = /usr/share/mysql
lc_messages = en_US
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address  = 0.0.0.0
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
max_connections  = 200
connect_timeout  = 5
wait_timeout  = 600
max_allowed_packet = 32M
thread_cache_size       = 128
sort_buffer_size = 4M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size  = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M
#
# * MyISAM
#
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched. On error, make copy and try a repair.
myisam_recover_options = BACKUP
key_buffer_size  = 128M
#open-files-limit = 2000
table_open_cache = 800
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 512M
concurrent_insert = 2
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 1M
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#

#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.
#
# we do want to know about network errors and such
log_warnings  = 2
#
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log[={0|1}]
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
long_query_time = 10
#log_slow_rate_limit = 1000
log_slow_verbosity = query_plan

#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#log_slow_admin_statements
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id  = 1
#report_host  = master1
#auto_increment_increment = 2
#auto_increment_offset = 1
log_bin   = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
log_bin_index  = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
# not fab for performance, but safer
#sync_binlog  = 1
expire_logs_days = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
# slaves
#relay_log  = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin
#relay_log_index = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin.index
#relay_log_info_file = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin.info
#log_slave_updates
#read_only
#
# If applications support it, this stricter sql_mode prevents some
# mistakes like inserting invalid dates etc.
#sql_mode  = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,TRADITIONAL
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
default_storage_engine = InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_open_files = 800
innodb_io_capacity = 50
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_thread_concurrency=0

#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem

#
# * Galera-related settings
#
[galera]
# Mandatory settings
#wsrep_on=ON
#wsrep_provider=
#wsrep_cluster_address=
#binlog_format=row
#default_storage_engine=InnoDB
#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#
# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#
#bind-address=0.0.0.0
#
# Optional setting
#wsrep_slave_threads=1

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet = 32M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completion

[isamchk]
key_buffer  = 32M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

How should I optimize mysql to load queries normally?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem or if there is a question. Are you wondering that your site responds slower when the DB is under high load due to an import process? Shouldn't that be rather expectable?

Comment: I think this is a problem and I would like to solve it. I think this is a problem with mysql optimization.

Comment: This actually belongs on dba.se. However - the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` looks quite small for modern hardware. You seem to have 3 GB free. But if your DB fits entirely into 256M, then it's fine. I would also review the `innodb_log_file_size`. Note that your bottleneck is probably not the CPU but the disk/storage.

Comment: Importing into the same table?  Importing with `INSERT`?  with `LOAD DATA`?  Other?  Which engine are you using?

Comment: How much RAM in the box?  How many CPU cores?  How large is the dataset?

Comment: Additional information request. # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server. Post on pastebin.com and share the links. From SSH login root, Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; E) complete MySQLTuner report AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - ulimit -a for a Linux/Unix list of limits, iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: To speed up all queries, please post additional information requested Dec 8, 2019 at 17:47.  Some suggestions will be made to improve your response time.

Answer (score 1):

(Need answers to the questions posed in Comments above before trying to answer the 2x question.  Meanwhile, let's try to speed up the query.)

```
SELECT
              SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS -- Costly; remove if don't need total count
          hm_posts.ID
    FROM  hm_posts
    WHERE  1=1
      AND  NOT EXISTS(    -- "semi-join" should be faster than IN or LEFT JOIN
                SELECT  1
                    FROM  hm_term_relationships  -- needs INDEX(object_id, term_taxonomy)
                    WHERE  object_id = hm_posts.ID 
                      AND  term_taxonomy_id IN (7)
                     )
      AND  hm_posts.post_type = 'product'
      AND  hm_posts.post_status IN ('publish', 'private')  -- simpler (not faster)
    -- useless:     GROUP BY  hm_posts.ID      -- remove
    ORDER BY  hm_posts.post_date DESC
    LIMIT  0, 10
```

Note:  `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` don't need the `GROUP BY`, but `LEFT JOIN` does.

Answer (score 0):

For you query i suggest firts a refactoring for avoid NOT IN clause and and use LEFT JOIN with chekc for null value

```
  SELECT DISTINCT DSQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS hm_posts.ID 
  FROM hm_posts 
  LEFT JOIN  hm_term_relationships 
    on hm_posts.ID = hm_term_relationships.object_id 
          AND hm_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 7 
  WHERE t.object_id is null
  AND hm_posts.post_type = 'product' 
  AND (hm_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR hm_posts.post_status = 'private')
```

looking to your query you have not aggreagtion function so instead of group by you should use DISTINCT

anyway for the use for DSQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWSis deprecated in mysql 8 so you could think to refactore you query for avoid this feature

Comment: This is not about the query because all queries are slower. I think this is about mysql optimization.

Comment: @TomHarisond  the first  optimiziation is avoid slow code  ..  a NOT IN clause produce bad performance  .. you can't get better performance using the same  code  ..

Comment: This can be made simpler and faster by `LEFT JOINing` directly to `hm_term_relationships`, instead of building a derived. table.

Comment: @RickJames .. correct .. answer updated  .. without subquery  ..(upvoted  somewhere)